# Discord Oauth2 authentication returns client_id undefined

Tags: oauth-2.0, discord, discord.js

I'm using authjs to authenticate users using discord provider in sveltekit app. I get an error when click to signIn using the provider disocrd :

The error :

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 400 ()

https://discord.com/api/oauth2/authorize?scope=identify+email&response_type=code&client_id=undefined&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A5173%2Fauth%2Fcallback%2Fdiscord&code_challenge=G7sFJrefQ&code_challenge_method=S256



authorize:1 Refused to apply inline style because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "default-src 'none'". Either the 'unsafe-inline' keyword, a hash ('sha256-4Su6mBWzEIFnH4pAGMOuaeBrstwJN4Z3pq/s1Kn4/KQ='), or a nonce ('nonce-...') is required to enable inline execution. Note that hashes do not apply to event handlers, style attributes and javascript: navigations unless the 'unsafe-hashes' keyword is present. Note also that 'style-src' was not explicitly set, so 'default-src' is used as a fallback.
```

Note client_id is undefined. Is this the client_id returned from the dicord server, meaning it doesn't return a user or this is the client_id which I enter when I contact the discord server?

I use the provider like so :

```
+page.svelte
     import { signIn, signOut } from '@auth/sveltekit/client';
    const handleDiscordSignIn = () => {
        signIn('discord', { callbackUrl: '/protected' });
    };
```

+hooks.server.js

```
import { SvelteKitAuth } from '@auth/sveltekit';
import DiscordProvider from "@auth/core/providers/discord"

providers: [
        GitHubProvider({clientId : "123", clientSecret :"...44595"}),
        DiscordProvider({cliendId :"123", clientSecret :"....8cea0" }),
        GoogleProvider({cliendId :"123", clientSecret :"....8cea0" })
]...rest of my code
```

Consider the following :

1-my google provider is working. I'm able to authenticate google users so the authjs code is not the problem

2-The discord code does contact the server and return the aforementioned error. That means I'm contacting the discord server but it doesn't return the user or the clientid I provided is empty.

That is why I'm asking if the client_id in that error is the id returned from the discord server for the user or the clientid I provided and posted above.

Any help regarding how to fix this or how to troubleshoot it would be appreciated as it's my first time dealing with discord service. Anyone with experience dealing with Discord Oauth2??

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you haven't added your discord bot's client id correctly or at all. Make sure you put the client id of your bot from [here](https://discord.com/developers/applications) instead of the user id of the user you are trying to authenticate.

Comment: I didn't add the bot id. I only created the application, wen to Oauth2 tab and copied the clientid,  secret and added the redirect url. I didn't touch the bot tab.The signIn function takes the name of the provider and callback?